# When is a closed immersion an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Today I learned that if $f:X \to Y$ is a closed immersion of schemes, then the sheaf map $f^\#: O_Y \to f_* O_X$ is surjective, which is equivalent to $f^\#_x: O_{Y,f(x)} \to O_{X,x}$ being surjective for all $x \in X$. So the only thing that remains for $f$ to be an isomorphism is the injectivity of $f^\#_x$ for all $x \in X$. I wonder if there are any natural conditions that give this injectivity (and hence make a closed immersion into an isomrphism).

Comment: 1. This is not true of all morphisms. I think you mean "if $f : X \to Y$ is a closed immersion of schemes..."

2. In order for $f$ to be an isomorphism, we need that $f_x^\#$ is an isomorphism for all $x$ *and* that $f : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism. (closed immersion implies homeo onto image, so in this case we just need that $f$ is surjective)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk thank you, I corrected the statement.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Does this mean that a surjective closed immersion is an isomorphism? This seems too good to be true!

Comment: The only natural condition that comes to mind is when the target is reduced, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914896/surjective-closed-immersion-into-an-integral-scheme-is-an-isomorphism/3914915#3914915) for instance. (This could be a potential duplicate of that question.)

Comment: No, I listed two conditions. For a closed immersion to be an isomorphism, it must be surjective *and* have the property that $f^\#_x$ is injective for all $x$.

Comment: Let's replace the phrase 'isomorphism' by 'clopen embedding', as this is the better notion here (e.g. obviously your $f$ won't be an isomorphism if $f$ is not surjective). Then, your closed embedding $f$ is a clopen embedding if and only if it is locally of finite presentation and flat. The one direction is clear, and the converse direction is given by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get this off of the answered list, let me just elaborate on what I said in the above comment.

Namely, let us say that $f\colon X\to Y$ is a *clopen embedding* if $f(X)\subseteq Y$ is a clopen(=closed and open) subset, and $f:X\to f(X)$ is an isomorphism, where $f(X)$ is given the open subscheme structure. Evidently a clopen embedding is an isomorphism if and only if it is surjective.

> **Observation:** *Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a closed embedding of schemes. Then, $f$ is a clopen embedding if and only if $f$ is locally
> of finite presentation and flat.*

*Proof:* If $f$ is a clopen embedding then it is flat and locally of finite presentation (in fact see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025G) for a much more interesting result). For the converse result, if $f$ is locally of finite presentation and flat then it is an open embedding by [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0819) (or the previously linked result!). Indeed, the only thing to observe is that being locally of finite presentation implies finite presentation since $f$ is automatically quasi-compact, being a closed embedding. The claim then follows, as $f$ being an open embedding implies that $f\colon X\to f(X)$ is an isomorphism, and $f(X)$ is clopen since $f$ is both an open and closed embedding. $\blacksquare$

Let me just note that both conditions are necessary:

- if $Y$ is locally Noetherian, then any closed embedding is (locally) of finite presentation, so it's easy to give counterexamples to the claim if we remove the flat hypothesis (e.g. $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x))\to \mathrm{Spec}(k[x])$,
- more surprisingly you cannot remove the locally of finite presentation property, and in fact the closed embedding $\mathrm{Spec}(R/I)\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is flat precisely when $I$ is pure (see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PS)), and the existence of closed but not clopen embeddings into connected schemes is quite difficult (c.f. [Proposition 5.4 + Proposition 7.2, [Lazard]](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/bsmf.1649.pdf)).